# how to remove showing html inside label tooltip - using joomla 3 bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Using Javascript...

How can I remove the html from the following tooltip:

[image]

Using Joomla 3 & Bootstrap 3.

Demo page: http://demov3.joostrap.com/contact-form

Comment: _"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."_ Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage), you should enable inserting HTML into tooltip.

`$('#example').tooltip({html : true})`